# click submit button automatically if a condition is satisfied

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am making an online examination system in PHP.this is a part of my huge examination code..every thing is working well.When the time is up, the page is redirecting to result page by

```
window.location = "http://localhost/result.php";//which is in comment line
```

but here the value of answers are not posting. But when i click the submit button it works.
So i make a function to submit the form automatically.but it is not working , dont know why.
Here "if" block is checking whether the time is up or not. if up then do the following.
Inside "if" I want either to click the "submit button"

```
 echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="SUBMIT"/></FORM>';
```

or submit the the form, so that i can get the result in next page- "result.php".

```
<FORM name ='form1' id='form1' method ='post' action='result.php' >
```

Thanks in advance. Hope you understand my problem.

```
function myfunc () {
    var frm = document.getElementById("form1");
    frm.submit();
}

document.getElementById("remain").innerHTML = hours+" hours : "+minutes+" minutes : "+seconds+" seconds";
SD=window.setTimeout( "setCountDown()", 1000 );
if (minutes == '00' && seconds == '00') { seconds = "00"; window.clearTimeout(SD);
    window.alert("Time is up. Press OK to continue.");
    window.onload = myfunc;
    //document.form1.submit();
    //window.location = "http://localhost/result.php"
}
```

Comment: Just a simple mistake, you're using `window.onload` wrong. Check the usage with the Javascript reference of your choice. If you complain about this commment, please share why actually you thought it should work, that part is missing from your question.

Comment: Given your `if` executes only after a certain time, giving `window.onload` doesn't make sense. Simply call the `myfunc();` after the alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use this
      document.form1.submit.click();

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
window.onload = function(){
    myfunc();
};
```

Comment: first of all thank u for your quick reply.but the fact is that it is still not working man! alert is coming. but after clicking "ok" it remains in the same page..it is not going to the result page..what is wrong..

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to submit the form after `window.alert("Time is up. Press OK to continue.")` shows, you don't need a load event. You can just put your code immediately after the alert and it will run once the alert is closed (by clicking 'okay'):

```
alert("Time is up. Press OK to continue.");
myfunc();
```

Alternatively, you could use `confirm` instead of `alert`:

```
var timesUp = confirm("Time is up. Press OK to continue.");

if (timesUp) {
    myfunc();
}
```

With a `confirm` you'll get two buttons and could run a different event for `ok` (true) and `cancel` (false). One of these options should solve your problem though.